# Переход по якорям с внутрених страниц

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость в написании скрипта. Но даже не знаю, с чего начать.

Вот код html:

```
<body class="index-body">
  <a name="media"></a>
  <a name="AbautUs"></a>
  <a name="index"></a>
</body>
```

Вот само меню:

```
<menu>
     <li> 
        <a href="#media">меню 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#AbautUs">меню 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#index">меню 3 </a>
    </li>
</menu>
```

Скрипт должен выполнять следующее: при заходе на странцу должен осуществляться переход по якорю "index", а если с внутрених страниц, то потому якорю, на который было нажато.

Причем, как это сделать по отдельности, я знаю, но вот как это осуществить вместе, ума не приложу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вначале не совсем понял, чего хочет автор, но в комментарии к ответу пришло больше понимания, поэтому рискну предложить такой вариант на JS, только добавьте всем блокам `id`, такие же как `name`, так проще перевести хэш в селектор:

```
// Для переходов с внешних ссылок
$(window).load(function() {
    var questionHash;
    if (window.location.hash) {
        questionHash = window.location.hash; // Если ссылка содержит хэш, то переходим на якорь по этому хэшу
    } else {
        questionHash = '#index'; // Если хэша нет, то переходим на якорь index
    }

    var offsetTop = questionHash === '#' ? 0 : $(questionHash).offset().top - 100;

    $("html,body").stop().animate ({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 10);
});

// Для внутренних ссылок на странице (это обычный вариант), заранее нужно присвоить всем ссылкам класс link
$('.link').click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: я немного по другому решил хотя вам ставлю ответ вот мое решение 
<html>
 <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
   function getAncor(){
  var linkUrl=window.location.href;
  var reg = "#";
  if(linkUrl.search(reg) !=-1){
   var theLinkUrl = linkUrl.split('#');
   return document.getElementsByName (theLinkUrl[0]) [0].scrollIntoView (0)
  }else{
   return document.getElementsByName ('index') [0].scrollIntoView (0)
   }
  }
  </script>
 </head>
        <body class="index-body" onload="getAncor()">

Comment: @Sergalas, в принципе у вас логика такая же, только на JS, а для определения хэша всё-таки советую использовать `window.location.hash`, чтобы не делать лишних телодвижений с урлом :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, например, один пункт меню `<a href="#media">меню 1 </a>`, далее вам нужно создать, например, `<div id="media"></div>`. И если тогда нажать на меню, окно прокрутится до этого дива. Если вам нужна плавная прокрутку, тогда надо использовать js.

Comment: Плавная прокрутка у меня уже организована. Вы не читали, что мне надо? Мне надо, чтобы при загрузке с нуля (скажем так, через поиск гугл, для примера) сразу был переход на определеный анкор. А если переход осушествляеться с внутрених страниц, то шел, к примеру, если выбрано меню 2, к анкору AbautUs. Но скрипт, который при загрузке отправляет к анкору, index загружается автоматом. Я так понимаю, здесь без ajax и php не обойтись.